# How to express the speed between two participants, $A$ and $B$, in terms of interval values $s^2$ between events on their trajectories?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, speed

For two participants, $A$ and $B$, contained in a flat region of spacetime, who met each other in passing at event $\varepsilon_{AB}$,
their speed wrt. each other at this event, $\beta[~AB~]~c$, can be defined by referring to two suitable inertial systems, $\Phi$ which contains a member who was comoving wrt. $A$ at event $\varepsilon_{AB}$, and $\Gamma$ which contains a member who was comoving wrt. $B$ at event $\varepsilon_{AB}$;
namely as
$$\beta[~AB~]~c := \beta_{\Phi}[~\Gamma~]~c = \beta_{\Gamma}[~\Phi~]~c.$$

Given the trajectory of $A$ as the (ordered) set events in which $A$ took part, $\{ ~ \varepsilon_{A~\Xi} ~ \}$, and the trajectory of $B$ as the (ordered) set events in which $B$ took part, $\{ ~ \varepsilon_{B~\Upsilon} ~ \}$, where event $\varepsilon_{AB}$ is a member of both sets,
and given the interval values for all pairs of these events, $s^2 : \left( \{ ~ \varepsilon_{A~\Xi} ~ \} \cup \{ ~ \varepsilon_{B~\Upsilon} ~ \} \right) \times    \left( \{ ~ \varepsilon_{A~\Xi} ~ \} \cup \{ ~ \varepsilon_{B~\Upsilon} ~ \} \right) \rightarrow \mathbb R$,

how to express the number $\beta[~AB~]$ in terms of these interval values?

Comment: Intervals are Lorentz invariant. Speeds, including relative speeds, are not. You need some information specifying in which reference frame you are working and need to use that.

Comment: @By Symmetry: "_Intervals are Lorentz invariant._" -- Right; they are proper. "_Speeds, including relative speeds, are not._" -- Speed, by its explicit definition, is necessarily "_relative_"; i.e. "**of**" someone or something (or "a phase") propagating "**in relation to**" a suitable system. Or as in the example of my question at least: in relation to someone else: "Speed **of** $A$ **in relation to** $B$, and vice versa. And this can be properly defined, too. "_You need some information specifying in which reference frame you are working and need to use that._" -- Obviously as described.

Answer (score -1):

Call participant $F$ the member of inertial system $\Phi$ who, together with $A$ and $B$, took part in event $\varepsilon_{AB} \equiv \varepsilon_{ABF}$, and call participant $G$ the member of inertial system $\Gamma$ who, together with $A$, $B$ and $F$, took part in event $\varepsilon_{AB} \equiv \varepsilon_{ABFG}$.

The speed of participant $F$ wrt. system $\Gamma$ is of course constant, and equal to the speed of participant $G$ wrt. $\Phi$:

$$\beta_{\Gamma}[~F~]~c = \beta_{\Phi}[~G~]~c := \beta[~\Phi~\Gamma~]~c = \text{const.}$$

If $\beta[~\Phi~\Gamma~] = 0$ then systems $\Phi$ and $\Gamma$ are identical, and simply $\beta[~A~B~] = 0$, too.

Otherwise $\beta[~\Phi~\Gamma~] \neq 0$, and $F$ and $G$ met only at event $\varepsilon_{ABFG}$. In this case participant $G$ also met and passed members of system $\Phi$ other than $F$. Consider (an otherwise arbitrary) one of them, $J$, who together with $G$ took part in event $\varepsilon_{GJ} \not\equiv \varepsilon_{ABFG}$. Thereby the following events can be uniquely identified, too:

- the event in which $F$ took part (passing any suitable participant $N$), $\varepsilon_{FN} \not\equiv \varepsilon_{ABFG}$, for which $s^2[~\varepsilon_{FN}, \varepsilon_{GJ}~] = 0$ and $|~s^2[~\varepsilon_{FN}, \varepsilon_{ABFG}~]~| \le |~s^2[~\varepsilon_{GJ}, \varepsilon_{ABFG}~]~|$,
- the event in which $F$ took part (passing any suitable participant $Q$), $\varepsilon_{FQ} \not\equiv \varepsilon_{ABFG}$, for which $s^2[~\varepsilon_{FQ}, \varepsilon_{GJ}~] = 0$ and $|~s^2[~\varepsilon_{FQ}, \varepsilon_{ABFG}~]~| \ge |~s^2[~\varepsilon_{GJ}, \varepsilon_{ABFG}~]~|$, and
- the event in which $F$ took part (passing some suitable participant $P$), $\varepsilon_{FP} \not\equiv \varepsilon_{ABFG}$, for which $s^2[~\varepsilon_{FN}, \varepsilon_{FP}~] = s^2[~\varepsilon_{FQ}, \varepsilon_{FP}~]$.

By [Einstein's definition of simultaneity](http://einsteinpapers.press.princeton.edu/vol6-trans/283?highlightText=perceives) $F$'s indication at event $\varepsilon_{FP}$ is simultaneous to $J$'s indication at event $\varepsilon_{GJ}$; $F_{\circ P} \equiv F_{\circledS J \circ G}$.

The (chronometric) distance between $F$ and $J$ is explicitly in terms of $F$'s ping duration wrt. $J$

$$\text{distance}[~F, J~] := \frac{1}{2}~c~\tau F[~{}_N, {}_Q~] = \frac{1}{2}~c~\sqrt{~|~s^2[~\varepsilon_{FN}, \varepsilon_{FQ}~]~|~},$$

and the duration of (the members of) system $\Phi$ being occupied while $G$ is passed between $F$ and $J$ is explicitly in terms of $F$'s duration

$$\text{trip duration}_{\Phi}[~G~] = \tau F[~{}_{\circ ABG}, {}_{\circledS J \circ G}~] \equiv \tau F[~{}_{\circ ABG}, {}_{\circ P}~] = \sqrt{~|~s^2[~\varepsilon_{ABFG}, \varepsilon_{FP}~]~|~}.$$

The constant speed of participant $G$ wrt. system $\Phi$ is expressed accordingly as

$$\beta_{\Phi}[~G~]~c := \frac{\text{distance}[~F, J~]}{\text{trip duration}_{\Phi}[~G~] } = \frac{c}{2}~\frac{\sqrt{~|~s^2[~\varepsilon_{FN}, \varepsilon_{FQ}~]~|~}}{\sqrt{~|~s^2[~\varepsilon_{ABFG}, \varepsilon_{FP}~]~|~}} = \frac{c}{2}~\sqrt{~\frac{s^2[~\varepsilon_{FN}, \varepsilon_{FQ}~]}{s^2[~\varepsilon_{ABFG}, \varepsilon_{FP}~]}~}.$$

Since $F$ is a member of an inertial system, the events in which $F$ took part are all (triple-wise) straight wrt. each other:

$$\! \sqrt{\frac{s^2[~\varepsilon_{FN}, ~ \varepsilon_{FQ}~]}{s^2[~\varepsilon_{ABFG}, ~ \varepsilon_{FQ}~]}} \! = \! 1 \! - \! \sqrt{\frac{s^2[~\varepsilon_{ABFG}, ~ \varepsilon_{FN}~]}{s^2[~\varepsilon_{ABFG}, ~ \varepsilon_{FQ}~]}}, ~ 2\sqrt{\frac{s^2[~\varepsilon_{ABFG}, ~ \varepsilon_{FP}~]}{s^2[~\varepsilon_{ABFG}, ~ \varepsilon_{FQ}~]}} \! = \! 1 \! + \! \sqrt{\frac{s^2[~\varepsilon_{ABFG}, ~ \varepsilon_{FN}~]}{s^2[~\varepsilon_{ABFG}, ~ \varepsilon_{FQ}~]}} \!.$$

Further, the symmetry between inertial systems $\Phi$ and $\Gamma$, and in particular the symmetry between $F$ and $G$ with respect to their meeting in event $\varepsilon_{ABFG}$ together with the interval relations of the setup description imply:

$$\sqrt{\frac{s^2[~\varepsilon_{ABFG}, ~ \varepsilon_{FN}~]}{s^2[~\varepsilon_{ABFG}, ~ \varepsilon_{FQ}~]}} = \frac{s^2[~\varepsilon_{ABFG}, ~ \varepsilon_{FN}~]}{s^2[~\varepsilon_{ABFG}, ~ \varepsilon_{GJ}~]} = \frac{s^2[~\varepsilon_{ABFG}, ~ \varepsilon_{GJ}~]}{s^2[~\varepsilon_{ABFG}, ~ \varepsilon_{FQ}~]}.$$

Consequently,

$$\! \beta_{\Phi}[~G~] \! = \! \frac{1}{2}~\sqrt{~\frac{s^2[~\varepsilon_{FN}, \varepsilon_{FQ}~]}{s^2[~\varepsilon_{ABFG}, \varepsilon_{FP}~]}~} \! = \! \Large{\frac{1 - \sqrt{\frac{s^2[~\varepsilon_{ABFG}, ~ \varepsilon_{FN}~]}{s^2[~\varepsilon_{ABFG}, ~ \varepsilon_{FQ}~]}}}{1 + \sqrt{\frac{s^2[~\varepsilon_{ABFG}, ~ \varepsilon_{FN}~]}{s^2[~\varepsilon_{ABFG}, ~ \varepsilon_{FQ}~]}}}} \! = \! \Large{\frac{1 - \frac{s^2[~\varepsilon_{ABFG}, ~ \varepsilon_{FN}~]}{s^2[~\varepsilon_{ABFG}, ~ \varepsilon_{GJ}~]}}{1 + \frac{s^2[~\varepsilon_{ABFG}, ~ \varepsilon_{FN}~]}{s^2[~\varepsilon_{ABFG}, ~ \varepsilon_{GJ}~]}}}.$$

Finally, since $A$'s trajectory approaches that of $F$ the closer they are to event $\varepsilon_{ABFG}$ (where they are comoving, at least momentarily), and since $B$'s trajectory approaches that of $G$ the closer they are to event $\varepsilon_{ABFG}$ (where they are comoving, at least momentarily), an expression of
 $\beta_{\Phi}[~G~]$, and by definition equivalently of $\beta[~AB~]$, is obtained as

$$\beta[~AB~] = \Large{\mathop{\text{lim}}_{s^2[~\varepsilon_{AB}, ~ \varepsilon_{B\Upsilon}~] \rightarrow 0}}\left[ \left. \left( \Large{\frac{1 - \frac{s^2[~\varepsilon_{AB}, ~ \varepsilon_{A \Xi}~]}{s^2[~\varepsilon_{AB}, ~ \varepsilon_{B \Upsilon}~]}}{1 + \frac{s^2[~\varepsilon_{AB}, ~ \varepsilon_{A \Xi}~]}{s^2[~\varepsilon_{AB}, ~ \varepsilon_{B \Upsilon}~]}}} \right) \right\vert_{{{s^2[~\varepsilon_{A \Xi}, ~ \varepsilon_{B \Upsilon}~] = 0,} \atop ~} \atop {\frac{s^2[~\varepsilon_{AB}, ~ \varepsilon_{A \Xi}~]}{s^2[~\varepsilon_{AB}, ~ \varepsilon_{B \Upsilon}~]} \le 1.}} \right]$$